# Mapping a single class to columns in two tables with Fluent nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I have the following database tables:

```
TABLE dbo.Client
(
  ClientId PK uniqueidentifier ,
  ClientNames VARCHAR(200)
)

TABLE dbo.User
(
  userID PK UniqueIdentifier,
  password varchar(15),
  passwordsalt varchar(15),
  ClientID FK uniqueidentifier
)
```

I want to map them to my class:

```
 public class Client
 {
   public virtual Guid Id {get;set;}
   public virtual string Name {get;set;}
   public virtual string password {get;set;}
   public virtual string passwordsalt {get;set;}
 }
```

I've sorted the mapping to the bits in the client table (excuse the vb...)

```
 Public Class ClientMap
   Inherits ClassMap(Of Client)

   Public Sub New()
     Me.Id(Function(x) x.Id, "ClientID")
     Me.Map(Function(x) x.Name, "ClientNames")
   End Sub

 End Class
```

How do I go about mapping the password & passwordsalt properties to the corresponding columns in the users table?

Thanks in advance,

Pau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved this problem...

My mapping file now looks like:

```
Public Sub New()
  Me.Id(Function(x) x.Id, "ClientID")
  Me.Map(Function(x) x.FullNames, "ClientNames")
  Me.Join("Users", AddressOf AddUsersTableInfo)
End Sub

Public Sub AddUsersTableInfo(ByVal m As JoinPart(Of Client))
  m.Map(Function(x) x.PasswordSalt, "passwordSalt")
  m.Map(Function(x) x.Password, "password")
End Sub
```

Got to love VB :o(